# Edit source data in embeddet Office 2016 chart

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint, office-2016

I am trying to edit the source data to a pre formatted waterfall chart in PowerPoint. However, the code crashes when trying to access the .ChartData.Workbook property.

Code crashes at first line:

`Set wbChart = cfSlide.Shapes("CFChart").chart.ChartData.Workbook
 Set wsChart = wbChart.Worksheets(1)`

The code works perfectly on old charts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't envy you for all the troubles the waterfall chart has given you.  You should try to get a free year of office from Microsoft for all your troubles :P

Answer (score 0):

From 2007 onwards, I believe it is necessary to `Activate` the workbook. This is a really terrible design/implementation, but in my experience it is necessary.

```
cfSlide.Shapes("CFChart").chart.ChartData.Workbook.Activate
Set wbChart = cfSlide.Shapes("CFChart").chart.ChartData.Workbook
wbChart.Application.WindowState = -4140    '## Minimizes Excel
Set wsChart = wbChart.Worksheets(1)
```

This gets nasty because then you have to minimize it and/or `.Close` it for minimal UI interruption. I like to minimize it immediately, and close it when finished, which you could do `wbChart.Close`

I think I have read elsewhere that you can avoid this by using a `With` block, but I've not been able to successfully implement that, e.g.:

```
With cfSlide.Shapes("CFChart").chart.ChartData.Workbook
    Set wsChart = .Worksheets(1)
    ' etc...

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2016 Powerpoint has a way to access the data behind a chart (not an Excel embedded object) XLWorkbook being the Excel file that holds the new data

```
For Each oSH In ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes

                    With oSH.Chart.ChartData

                            'this updates the values in the datasheet
                            .Workbook.sheets(1).Range("A1:B" & lastrow ).Value = xlWorkBook.sheets(2).Range("A3:B" & lastrow).Value

                    End With
```